# Want to create Stored Procedure of new table with calculated variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sas

I want to create a stored procedure using the table from Oracle and want to access in SAS EG.

I have below code .

```
create table xyz as 
select * from (   
  select a,b,c,d   
  from   table_name  
)   
pivot (MIN('X') for Variable_name in (   
  'PQR' as PQR, 'PGT' as PGT, 'KLD' as KLD, 
 'opd' as opd
  )    
)   
order  by Variable_name;
```

Is it possible to make this table as stored procedure? And if not then please suggest solution.

Comment: What do you mean by making a table as a stored procedure? Do you need a stored procedure which, when run, will create a table?

Comment: Maybe you're trying to create a view that does that pivot query, rather than a table that has the results at a fixed point in time? You could have a function that returns a pipelined table type but a view looks suitable here.

Comment: @nitish yes I want to create stored procedure which,when run, will create 
 a table.

Comment: You're really want your procedure to create a new permanent table - with a name you pass in, presumably - which contains the result of that query? Creating tables at run-time is generally not a good idea. Who/what will then query the table? Another option is to create a global temporary table (once) and have your procedure populate it for your session. Maybe if you edit the question to explain the problem you are trying to solve and what SAS EG is expected to do it will become clearer.

Comment: @AkshayPatil: If that is what you want you can make use of [`Dynamic SQL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011). However, it'll be better if you listen to Alex's suggestions.

Comment: Yes @alex I m new to oracle . I have transposed a table in oracle using above query Now i want to create a store process so that I can call that stored process in SAS.

Comment: Can you explain why you can't just run that query from SAS, or create a view that SAS queries? Creating a table is very different from calling a procedure that returns a result set. Without more information about what SAS is doing it isn't clear if you really need a view, a GTT, a pipelined function, or even something that returns a ref cursor.

Comment: @alex well we have large amount of data which is taking time in SAS so we had done in Oracle. So you mean to say we cant call a procedure which returns a result set??

Comment: You want to create an oracle stored procedure or a SAS stored process?  It should be possible to create a SAS stored process which would connect to Oracle and send that SQL to Oracle as an explicit pass-through query.  The query would execute on Oracle and return XYZ as a SAS dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly you should be able to do this using SQL pass-through. You will just need to specify the Oracle database in the `libname` statement in SAS which will look something like this:

```
libname mydblib oracle user=user_name password=pw path='myoracleserver';
```

You can then access this using `proc sql` in SAS.

```
proc sql;
connect using mydblib;

create table xyz as
select * from connection to mydblib (
select * from (   
  select a,b,c,d   
  from   table_name  
)   
pivot (MIN('X') for Variable_name in (   
  'PQR' as PQR, 'PGT' as PGT, 'KLD' as KLD, 
 'opd' as opd
  )    
)   
order by Variable_name
);
quit;
```

This code creates the table `xyz` in your SAS work library.

Comment: we have tried this query but getting below error:
ERROR: The ETLDM engine cannot be found.
ERROR: A Connection to the etldm DBMS is not currently supported, or is not installed at your site.

Comment: What version of SAS EG are you using? You may need to upgrade to version 7.12 per: http://support.sas.com/kb/59/266.html